# List object to DataFrame | Tabula | read_pdf_with_template

Tags: python, python-3.x, tabula, tabula-py

#### Problem Statement:

I'm using [Tabula App](https://tabula.technology/) user interface for selecting **dimension** of table from PDF file as **tabula-template** to give dimension in **JSON** Format.

The DataFrame in Tabula App Interface from extracting table after selecting Table dimension is correct.

However, when I'm using [`read_pdf_with_template`](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf_with_template) method which is returning **List** object. When I'm converting this List Object to DataFrame then its merging different columns.

---

#### Code Snippet:

```
tables = tabula.read_pdf_with_template(f, "tabula_saved.json")
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.concat([c for c in tables]).drop_duplicates()
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) < df.shape[1] - 2].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

#### DataFrame

The **DataFrame** in Tabula App interface:

```
| Txn Date    | Value Date | Brn Code | Particulars                 | Ref No | Debit     | Credit      | Balance           |
|-------------|------------|----------|-----------------------------|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 | 7777     | 31-JAN-18M2M Cash Dep Chrgs |        | 202.00    |             | 40,233.11   |
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 | 4115     | NEFT : 00003- TV 18 HOME    |        |           | 5,52,743.00 | 5,92,976.11 |
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 | 4115     | NEFT : AXISP1-TECH          |        |           | 25,252.00   | 6,18,228.11 |
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 | 1221     | To ECS  : ECS-TP UIA        | 911387 | 66,733.00 |             | 5,51,495.11 |
```

---

The **DataFrame** after using `read_pdf_with_template` method to return **list** and then converting it to **DataFrame**

```
| 0           | 1                                                     | 2           |
|-------------|-------------------------------------------------------|-------------|
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 7777 31-JAN-18M2M Cash Dep Chrgs 202.00    | 40,233.11   |
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 4115 NEFT : 00003- TV 18 HOME  5,52,743.00 | 5,92,976.11 |
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 4115 NEFT : AXISP1-TECH 25,252.00          | 6,18,228.11 |
| 01/02/2018  | 01/02/2018 1221 To ECS  : ECS-TP UIA 911387 66,733.00 | 5,51,495.11 |
```

---

> Note: Please Ignore the columns header in this question.